# Convert numbers from base X to base Y

Tags: javascript, mathematics, ecmascript-6, number-systems

I recently wrote a piece of code to convert between two bases of X, (Where 26 > X > 0). I was mighty proud that I did this. And then I started wondering, am I using modern coding conventions/practices?

The code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/PheoOneWhoMade/b7e97612e852ba2d5a3557b8b55e1bef).

And some sample outputs are shown:

```
// syntax: convertBase(input, inputBase, outputBase)
convertBase("10", 10, 11) // "a"
convertBase("3", 10, 3)   // "10"
convertBase("4", 10, 3)   // "11"
```

The full code is here:

```
function convertBase(inNumber, inBase, outputBase) {
  var result = [];
  if (typeof inNumber !== "number" && typeof inNumber !== "string") {
    throw new Error("You input is not a number or a string.");
  }
  var encodings = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  if (typeof inNumber === "number") {
    inNumber = JSON.stringify(inNumber);
  }
  if (inBase === outputBase) {
    return inNumber;
  }
  inNumber = inNumber.toLowerCase();
  inNumber = inNumber.split("").map(function(item) {
    return encodings.indexOf(item);
  });
  inNumber = inNumber.reverse();
  inNumber = inNumber.map(function(item, index) {
    return item * Math.pow(inBase, index);
  });
  var res = 0;
  inNumber.forEach(function(item) {
    res += item;
    return;
  });
  var ones = res % outputBase;
  var remainder = (res - res % outputBase) / outputBase;
  result.unshift(ones);
  var left = remainder > 1;
  while (left) {
    var ones = remainder;
    var remainder = (remainder - remainder % outputBase) / outputBase;
    result.unshift(ones);
    var left = remainder > 1;
  }
  return result.map(function(item) {
    return encodings[item];
  }).join("");
}
;
```

Comment: *(Where 26 > X > 0).*   Base 1 does not seem to have much utility.

Comment: @radarbob XD no it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bug

I tried converting `"10'` from base 10 to base 2 (i.e. binary) and the output was `250`, which is invalid for a base 2 number.

Also, when I ran `convertBase("3", 10, 3)` the output was `0`, not `"10"`

#### Your Question

> am I using modern coding conventions/practices?

Originally, before I added the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, this question only had the [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) tag. I don't see many [features of es-6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla) in your code, like [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters), etc. So judging from an [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) point-of-view, I would say **No**. See the rewrite below which utilizes those features.

```js
const convertBase = (inNumber, inBase = 10, outputBase = 10) => {
  let result = [];
  if (typeof inNumber !== "number" && typeof inNumber !== "string") {
    throw new Error("You input is not a number or a string.");
  }
  const encodings = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  if (typeof inNumber === "number") {
    inNumber = JSON.stringify(inNumber);
  }
  if (inBase === outputBase) {
    return inNumber;
  }
  inNumber = inNumber.toLowerCase();
  inNumber = inNumber.split("").map(item => encodings.indexOf(item));
  inNumber = inNumber.reverse();
  inNumber = inNumber.map((item, index)  => item * Math.pow(inBase, index));
  let res = 0;
  inNumber.forEach(item => res += item);
  let ones = res % outputBase;
  let remainder = (res - res % outputBase) / outputBase;
  result.unshift(ones);
  let left = remainder > 1;
  while (left) {
    ones = remainder;
    remainder = (remainder - remainder % outputBase) / outputBase;
    result.unshift(ones);
    left = remainder > 1;
  }
  return result.map(item => encodings[item]).join("");
};
console.log('convertBase("10", 10, 11):',convertBase("10", 10, 11))
```

#### Re-declarations

The code inside the `while` loop contains variable declarations for variables declared outside the loop:

> ```
> var ones = res % outputBase;
> var remainder = (res - res % outputBase) / outputBase;
> result.unshift(ones);
> var left = remainder > 1;
> while (left) {
>   var ones = remainder;
>   var remainder = (remainder - remainder % outputBase) / outputBase;
>   result.unshift(ones);
>   var left = remainder > 1;
> }
> ```

While the Javascript engine won't "*chuck a wobbly*<sup>[1](http://spencertipping.com/js-in-ten-minutes/js-in-ten-minutes.pdf)</sup>"<sup>[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/129277/213844)</sup> (<sub>though somebody who has to update your code might</sub>), those assignment statements inside the `while` loop could exist without the [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword, and for the sake of readability, probably should not have `var` at the beginning.

#### Simplification

The first versions of Ecmascript (i.e. 1 and 5) have had [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [Number.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString), which should be enough to implement the desired functionality (though note that the supported base values are 2-36, not 0-26).

```js
const convertBase = (inputNumber, inputBase = 10, outputBase = 10) =>
  parseInt(inputNumber, inputBase).toString(outputBase);

console.log('convertBase("10", 10, 11):', convertBase("10", 10, 11)); // "a"
console.log('convertBase("3", 10, 3):', convertBase("3", 10, 3)); // "10"
console.log('convertBase("4", 10, 3):', convertBase("4", 10, 3)); // "11"
console.log('convertBase(10, 10, 2):', convertBase(10, 10, 2)); // "1010"
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://spencertipping.com/js-in-ten-minutes/js-in-ten-minutes.pdf</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>https://english.stackexchange.com/a/129277/213844</sub>

Comment: \*frowns\* Looks like I didn't debug well.